# Java Opencv not detecting contours. imgproc.Drawcontours()

Tags: java, android, opencv, xamarin

I am trying to develop a mobile application on Xamarin. Firstly I'm doing it for the android device. I want the Oncamera function to automatically detect the contours and measure the size of the object. As a primary step I am trying to detect the contours in real-time. Read lot of forms and many documents but nothing helped me

```
public Mat OnCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.ICvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
    {
        Mat input = inputFrame.Rgba();
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Mat gray = new Mat();
        //Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
        Imgproc.CvtColor(p0: input, p1: gray, p2: Imgproc.ColorRgb2gray);
        Mat blur = new Mat();
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(gray, blur, new Size(7, 7), -2);
        Mat thresh = new Mat();
        Imgproc.Threshold(blur, thresh, 127, 250, Imgproc.ThreshBinary);
        Mat edged = new Mat();
        Imgproc.Canny(thresh, thresh, 25, 50);
        Imgproc.Dilate(thresh, thresh, new Mat(), new Point(-1, 1), 1);
        Mat hierarchy = thresh.Clone();
        Imgproc.FindContours(hierarchy, contours, new Mat(), 
             Imgproc.RetrExternal, Imgproc.ChainApproxNone);
        Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Out.Println("contours" + contours);
        if (contours != null)
        {
                Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Out.Println("found contours");
            for (int i = 0; i < contours.Count(); i++)
            {
                Imgproc.DrawContours(input, contours, i, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), -1);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Out.Println("no contours");
        }
        return input;
```

I used the above logic in the  code. But my output in the application is displaying normal image without any contours drawn on it. If I return the "thresh", then canny edge detection is perfectly working. But Drawcontours is not showing up anything.
I used Contours.count() because my Xamarin ide is showing error for contours.Size();

Comment: You don't need to loop through all contours to draw them. Remove the `for` loop and replace i with `-1`, this will draw all contours.

Comment: @Jyr I tried like that also. But I was not able to draw any contour in realtime. I'm not able to understand where it is going wrong!!

Comment: @Shofwan Amrullah can you please check this out?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
in my case I have replaced

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
```

with

```
IList<MatOfPoint> contours = new JavaList<MatOfPoint>();
```